# Flutter : How to Get all SharedPreferences keys except some Keys

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I want to get All SharedPreferences Keys except two keys

I can't use getString(Key) Method since there are N Keys.

```
Future<List<Widget>> getAllPrefs() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // I won't print those two keys neither remove them
    // prefs.remove("lib_cached_image_data");
    // prefs.remove("lib_cached_image_data_last_clean");
    prefs.setString("Market", "position");
    prefs.setString("Home", "position");
    return prefs.getKeys().map<Widget>((key) {
      //this is incorrect
      if (key != "lib_cached_image_data" && key != "lib_cached_image_data") {
        ListTile(
          title: Text(key),
          subtitle: Text(prefs.get(key).toString()),
        );
      }
    }).toList(growable: false);
  }
```

I expect the output : All ("Keys", "Values") except ("lib_cached_image_data",value) , ("lib_cached_image_data_last_clean",value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `where`. Don't forget to return the `ListTile` as well.

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.getKeys().where((String key) => key != "lib_cached_image_data" && key != "lib_cached_image_data").map<Widget>((key) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(key),
      subtitle: Text(prefs.get(key).toString()),
    );
}).toList(growable: false);
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)