# Flutter shared_preferences - how to get all the stored values begin with specific word

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have stored in shared_preferences key value pairs like below....

1. item_001 = 'some data'
2. item_103 = 'some data'
3. item_007 = 'some data'
4. item_059 = 'some data'

I am trying get all the stored values begins with `item_***`

I know how to read and write with single key (example below)... but I am trying to get a list of items from `shared_preferences` where the key name begins with `item_`.

**string**

```
read: final myString = prefs.getString('my_string_key') ?? '';
write: prefs.setString('my_string_key', 'hello');
```

**stringList**

```
read: final myStringList = prefs.getStringList('my_string_list_key') ?? [];
write: prefs.setStringList('my_string_list_key', ['horse', 'cow', 'sheep']);
```

due to some reason, I don't want to store all the items in one list.... I want to store each item with separate key.

I searched in google and in stackoverflow, unfortunately no where found proper answer....

also I looked into this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55733553/flutter-how-to-get-all-sharedpreferences-keys-except-some-keys), but not understood how to implement partial key search...

Answer (score 1):

esetintis got to this first but I doodled this code so I guess I'll share it. But yes, you have to first get all of the keys in the shared preferences and then get the value for matching keys.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
Set<String> keys = prefs.getKeys().where((key)=>key.startsWith('item_'));
for (String key in keys) {
  String value = prefs.getString(key); // Throws an error if you store something other than a String
  // Do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to make such query. However, you can tackle the issue with some extra steps.

1 step :

Get all `keys` from `SharedPreferences` with `prefs.getKeys()` method. This will return a `Set` of keys. Now you can assign a `List<String> keys = prefs.getKeys().where((k)=>k.startsWith('item_'))` which will have the keys you want to get from the `Storage`.

2nd :

Iterate the filtered array and get the values you want by calling `SharedPreferences`, and save them to some variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have all the keys in a list, for example:

```
List<String> keys = ['item_001', 'item_103', 'item_007', 'item_059', 'other_key', 'blablabla'];
```

Now, you could iterate through all of them and checking the ones that *starts with* "item_", like this:

```
  var itemKeys = [];
  
  for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    if (keys[i].startsWith('item_')) {
      itemKeys.add(keys[i]);
    }
  }
  
  print(itemKeys); // [item_001, item_103, item_007, item_059]
```

In the above example, `itemKeys` contains all the needed keys for you. What you could also do is to add the proper logic to fetch values from the shared preferences inside the `if` statement in the loop:

```
  var result = [];
  
  for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    if (keys[i].startsWith('item_')) {
      result.add(prefs.getString(keys[i]) ?? '');
    }
  }
```

`result` should contain what are you looking for.